# Best practice for testing reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Does anyone have a best practice on how to test huge data sets?

For example, I have a report page that runs this SQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.id) AS order_items,
       DATE(order_items.created_on)   AS date
FROM orders
JOIN order_items                  ON order_items.order_id = orders.id
JOIN shipments                    ON shipments.id = order_items.shipment_id
JOIN transactions                 ON transactions.order_id = orders.id
JOIN customers                    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
LEFT JOIN flagged_transactions ON flagged_transactions.transaction_id = transactions.id
WHERE orders.state NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', '')
 AND customers.state NOT IN ('fraud', 'maybe_fraud')
 AND shipments.state NOT IN ('cancelled', 'shipped')
 AND shipments.vendor_id = %{some_vendor}
 AND order_items.quantity > 0
 AND order_items.state IN ('initial', 'approve')
 AND order_items.created_on BETWEEN %{start_date} AND %{end_date}
 AND (flagged_transactions.id IS NULL OR flagged_transactions.state NOT IN ('pending'))
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

In a spec this became a huge mess of factories, one or several for each object.

Does anyone have ideas or best practice on how to do that more gracefully?

Comment: Are you hitting a huge production-type database? Instead, create a small test database that only contains a single or a few possible results for the query.

Comment: unit-testing is meant to test _code_, not _data_. You need to mock data for each scenario, and test that you get the expected result. The mock data needs to be the minimal example of the scenario you want to test.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan, but I'm of course hitting only test database. My question is about how to seed this database gracefully instead of calling gazzilions of factories.

Comment: @UriAgassi, you recommend to mock response from database and use mocked response. But this isn't helping much when there is a possibility for schema to change and not preventing from incorrect SQL query. Thus will be dangerous to refactoring in a future.

Comment: @sharkzp - testing compatibility with the schema is not part of the unit testing. It is more like a system test or an integration test.  This test should be simply seeing that the query passes, rather than it works.

Comment: @UriAgassi agreed. But you still need to populate large data preset for a integration/acceptance test. And such preset will be hard to maintain or change in a future. Any ideas on how to simplify that?

Comment: why do you need a _large_ dataset for integration/acceptance test?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of techniques you can employ:

- define high level factories for orders that would be present in the result set, i.e. wouldn't be filtered out by the where clause. Have some parameters be customizable, like date. Reference the factory by a name that makes sense to the report
- break the query where clause into a different method so you can test filtering and aggregation separately. That will allow you to test things with smaller data sets as you don't need to aggregate a lot of data to prove all the filters work
- break the filters in a pipeline that adds back to the next filter. For example: exclude fraud clients, exclude flagged transactions, exclude shipped or cancelled shipments, and each step of the way add to ids to be excluded. That way you can test each part independently with simpler factories. That can have positive or negative impacts on performance depending on your dataset
- Have just basic test coverage proving that happy-paths and most common cases are covered

Comment: Thanks @rafb3 but breaking this SQL apart will decrease it performance. Unfortunately neither arel/sequel/active_record are fast to perform and generate reports because of object instantiation and many other small things. But your idea in general good.